# Images side by side in an array xcode (in UITableViewCell)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an array of images (can be up to 25) that need to go side by side (they're access icons telling what facilities a location has)

I have the images in an array and have played around with using UIImageView in a UITableViewCell. (before trying the array, i'm practicing with static images). However, they overlap each other. Is there a way to force the images to the right of the previous one without working out the padding +60 pixels the right each time:

```
if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage];
        // I am assuming this image never changes and there is one row in this section! If it does change, use viewWithTag to get hold of the image view.
        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierImage] autorelease];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,50,50)]autorelease];
            imageView.tag = 1;
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];

            [cell addSubview:imageView];

            UIImageView *imageView2 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60,0,50,50)]autorelease];
            imageView2.tag = 2;
            imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prem.jpg"];

            [cell addSubview:imageView2];

        }
        return cell;

    }
```

The above works for two images, however it's not very elegant and seems silly to do that over 25 potential images (each time the number of images changes too).

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Tom

Comment: I would ditch the table view and use a UIScrollView..

Comment: I would, but theres a lot more information in the table already, and I need to use a table apparently according to the powers that be!

Comment: I would make a UITableViewCell subclass which has a method append image, and it internally can take care of laying out the image in the correct place, that way you dont have to worry about any of that in your table view view controller, well this is assuming you are not reusing cells, tho the way you have it above reusing cells, you will probably get images in the wrong cells..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a UIScrollView? If I ever need to lay down images side by side I just do that on a UIScrollView. The code looks something like this

```
//Let's say your UIScrollView is named 'scrollView' and the array containing your UIImages is called 'imageArray'

CGFloat contentWidth = 0;

for(UIImage *thisImage in imageArray)
{
    UIImageView *thisImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([imageArray indexOfObject:thisImage]*(thisImage.size.width + PADDING_IF_ANY), 0, thisImage.size.width, thisImage.size.height)];
    [scrollView addSubview:thisImageView];
    [thisImageView release];

    contentWidth += thisImage.size.width + ([imageArray indexOfObject:thisImage]==0)?0:PADDING_IF_ANY;
}

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentWidth, scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Code explanation:

PADDING_IF_ANY means the pixel padding you want between two images. The code is simply a for loop that loops over your UIImage array, allocated a UIImageView for each image, and sets the X-origin based on the index position of the UIImage in the array.

Hence, index position 0 will be laid at the left most position in the scroll view. Index position 1 will be laid at 1*(image width + padding) i.e. to the right of the previous image in the scrollview, and so on.

To use a scrollView in a UITableViewCell do this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//This line gets you the frame of the cell relative to the tableview.
CGRect cellFrame = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//Set the Y origin to 0. This will get you the frame for the scrollView to be added with to the cell.
cellFrame.origin.y = 0;

//Now add your scrollView
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame];
/*
Do stuff
*/
[cell.contentView addSubview:scrollView];
[scrollView release];
```

Comment: Can I use a scrollview in a cell?

Comment: Does that require a custom cell view, or can I litterally do it in the cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: Hi, Thakns for this i'm sure it will help and I will mark it up when I get it working! Can I ask a quick question? IF i add a UIScrollView to my xib file to work with this, do I have to put it on the table or will it automatically move it in to place on the xib. Or do I have to programatically add the scrollview somehow?

Comment: Honestly, I do not use IB so I am not sure. But to make an educated guess, I would say, do it programmatically. The code I posted in the answer should help...

Answer (score 1):

Create the rects based upon ivar integer values and put it in a for loop which increments the xpos ivar each time round the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use a horizontal table view with CGTransform like that:
http://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/creating-pulse-style-scrolling-horizontally-scrolling-uitableview-as-a-subview-of-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change this line

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
```

i know this may increase memory but there is no other solution then it or just use scrollview.